# Declaring array of receiver methods

Tags: go

Here's a small example using an array of functions.  I want to convert this to an array of receiver methods.  What would be the proper declaration for the array on line 11?  https://play.golang.org/p/G62Cxm-OG2
The function declarations would change from:
func addToStock(s *Stock, add int)
To:
func (s *Stock) addToStock(add int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like these:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Stock struct {
    qty int
}

var updaters = [2]func(*Stock, int){
    func(s *Stock, i int){s.add(i)},
    func(s *Stock, i int){s.remove(i)},
}

func main() {
    s := Stock{10}

    fmt.Println("Stock count =", s.qty)

    updaters[0](&s, 2)

    fmt.Println("Stock count =", s.qty)

    updaters[1](&s, 5)

    fmt.Println("Stock count =", s.qty)
}

func (s *Stock)add(add int) {
    s.qty += add
}

func (s *Stock)remove(sub int) {
    s.qty -= sub
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!  I was thinking in the wrong direction, trying to add the receiver to the array declaration like this:
    var updaters = [2](*Stock)func(int) {...